# discussion for concurrency when using reference value

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, reference

when writing concurrency program, sometimes we use the reference parameter, assume it is `ref1` with fake type `Reference`, a method like

```
public void testRefVarInMethod(Reference ref1) {
   Reference ref2 = ref1;
   ....
   ....
}
```

In this method, I declare a new variable `ref2` which points to `ref1`. We all know that method variable is thread safe, however, as to reference `ref1`, anybody can change its value outside the method, so the `ref2`'s value will be changed  too. I guess this cannot guarantee thread safe, why do some people write code like this?

Answer (score 0):

That's why people use methods like `clone` to ensure thread-safety.

```
Reference ref2 = ref1.clone();
```

By referencing the copy of ref1, ref2 will not be affected regardless how ref1 is changed by some other threads.

**Edit:**
As pointed out in the comments, the `clone` method does not necessarily enforce thread-safety. It has to be correctly implemented in a way that modifying `ref1` will not change the state of `ref2`. i.e., `ref1` and `ref2` do not share any mutable fields.

Comment: There are many potential problems with `clone()` and it is incorrect to presume that all uses of it will lead to correct programs.  I'm not the down voter.

Comment: @scottb Yes I agree, the `clone` method has to be correctly implemented. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the local variable `ref2` itself cannot be changed outside your method (none can make it point to another object from outside). It's only the state of the object it references that can be changed (someone can call `ref1.setField(newValue)`) concurrently.

People do that because they need to share objects between threads. Otherwise, they wouldn't be able to gain benefits of multithreading in many cases.

But people don't do it recklessly, they usually introduce various forms of synchronization to guarantee thread safety. For instance, one can use `synchronized` section as the simplest and most straightforward tool to delineate a critical section that can be executed by only one thread at any given time:

```
synchronized(ref2) {
    // Change or read object here
}
```

If all the code uses the same approach, making changes (and reading them) on the object will be safe.

There're many other, more specialised and more efficient, synchronization primitives and techniques that you should learn about if you're going to write multithreaded programs with shared objects: immutability, `volatile`, `ReadWriteLock` etc. Books like "Java Concurrency in Practice" can give you a good introduction into the field.

Comment: Thanks, I've finished reading the excellent book 'Java Concurrency in Practice'